# How to add a graphical filter to Linux (ubuntu) graphical output?

Tags: linux, filter, graphical-programming

I would like to add a (custom) graphical filter to my Ubuntu desktop, for example to add graphical effects like deformations or color filtering on some conditions (mouse move, for example).

The idea is to be able to process the image data just before it is sent to the video card. Is it possible with a simple C program ? How ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think it is possible with a SIMPLE C program... Most probably you will end up with a very complex one. Did you try compiz?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll investigate to see if compiz fits my needs. Maybe there's already a plugin for what I need, or else I'll try to write one. I'll come back if I need more help ;-). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible with a SIMPLE C program... Most probably you will end up with a very complex one.
Did you try compiz?